# Passing data from modal to presenting vc using Swinject+Assembly

Tags: dependency-injection, rx-swift, swinject

I'm working on a project using RxSwift + Swinject + Assembly but they are quite new to me.
I'm having a modal controller for filters selection. It uses FilterViewModel with all available filters.
I'm wondering how to pass selected filters to presenting view controller?
I now I could cast presenting view controller to expected type and set the filters as vc's property but I would like to make it proper way using DI and assembly.

Comment: assembly as in an assembly language? I suspect that it not what you meant, but the tag says otherwise. Is the Assembly tag incorrect?

Comment: I removed that tag - it's swinject assembly protocol

Comment: one option might be: persist the filters (temporarily) and inject a viewModel into your modal controller. That view model will read your filters from where ever they were stored.